# Error en una variable definida

Tags: php, laravel, controller

Estoy realizando una web de noticias y no comprendo el siguiente error que me tira Laravel: **Undefined variable: notas**

En el controller tengo lo siguiente

```
public function show($id){
    $vistaNotas = notas::find($id);
      return view ('noticias')->with([
        'notas' => $notas]);

  }
```

No comprendo porque arriba más arriba tengo la misma funcion y si lo encuentra

```
public function index(){
  $notas = notas::all();
  return view('noticias')
  ->with([
    'notas' => $notas]);

  }
```

Luego en la vista hay un foreach de $notas as $nota, pero no creo que ese sea el problema

Gracias

Comment: Si revisas con detalle cada línea de código, verás que `$notas` no está definido en el primer código, revisa esta línea: `$vistaNotas = notas::find($id);`

Comment: es porque en la funcion  `show($id){` la llamastes `$vistaNota` y no `$notas`